# Why can't I change the window icon on a QMessageBox with setIcon in PySide6?

Tags: python, qt, qwidget, pyside6, qmessagebox

I have been following an [online tutorial](https://www.pythonguis.com/tutorials/pyside6-dialogs/) and corresponding book by Martin Fitzpatrick to get familiar with PySide6. On the topic of message boxes, it is mentioned there that we can change the icon that appears on the pop up window, but no matter what I try, no matter what specific icon I request, the "default" one (a python rocket for me) keeps popping up.

[image: Default icon appearing on QMessageBox even when Question is requested]

This is the code I am using so far

```
import sys

from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QMessageBox

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("My App")

        button = QPushButton("Press me for a dialog!")
        button.clicked.connect(self.button_clicked)
        self.setCentralWidget(button)

    def button_clicked(self, s):
        dlg = QMessageBox()
        dlg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Question)
        button = dlg.exec()

        if button == QMessageBox.Ok:
            print("OK!")

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = MainWindow()
window.show()

app.exec()
```

As you can see, the dlg variable refers to a recently constructed QMessageBox() to which I attempt to set a specific icon among the provided ones (`QMessageBox.Question`).

What am I missing? I have also tried with `QMessageBox.Icons.Question` since I saw that suggested online, but to no success.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try by adding the parent to the message box constructor: `dlg = QMessageBox(self)`

Comment: Already had it before, actually. It doesn't change anything, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Then it could be a Qt bug, or the installation may be corrupt due to missing icons. Try to add `app.setStyle('fusion')` after creating the QApplication instance. Also see the result of `app.style().standardIcon(QtWidgets.QStyle.SP_MessageBoxQuestion).isNull()`.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't seem to make a difference. The result of the instruction you suggest is `False`, which I interpret to mean the icons are indeed there. For some reason, the "Native Dialogs" don't seem to work, even if the icons are actually there

Comment: Well, my short answer is that development with Apple devices is a bi*ch. They have their own and extremely closed, inconsistent, unreliable way of doing things, completely disregarding backward compatibility, external development, proper user support and lots of other aspects that make development a painful hell for anybody that wants to do cross-platform programming and hasn't enough funding (aka, money) to have some leverage on their dull way of thinking or proper development support. That said, I'll look more into this tomorrow to give you a more appropriate answer without further rants ;-)

Comment: That's fair enough :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Musicamante's comments, it is a Qt bug. You can see [an old issue](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-88928) which failed to attract core developers.

You can disable a preference for a native dialog, like this.

```
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt
...

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    ...
    def button_clicked(self, s):
        app.setAttribute(Qt.ApplicationAttribute.AA_DontUseNativeDialogs, True)
        dlg = QMessageBox()
        dlg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Question)
        button = dlg.exec()
        app.setAttribute(Qt.ApplicationAttribute.AA_DontUseNativeDialogs, False)
...
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
...
```

It's up to you whether to avoid native dialogs or not. If a native dialog works well, it would be better to use it because it has more features of the underlying OS. For the `QFileDialog` API, they provide a special `DontUseNativeDialog` option. (I guess there were some complaints about a native file dialog.)

Comment: That actually worked! The layout is a bit clunky though, but I guess I can tweak it myself? In any case, could you please elaborate/speculate on why "native dialogs" may not work for me and what are the downsides of not being able to rely on them? Thanks!

Comment: I updated the answer, but I'm not sure that's what you want.